# Update de usuário Firebase com Node SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase

Estou tentando atualizar dados de login de um usuário do firebase usando o sdk admin do Node. Meu código tem esta aparência:

```
var uid = req.body.uid;
var objectUpdate = {
    "displayName": "David Coelho"
};
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, objectUpdate)
    .then(função(userRecord) {
        // var id = userRecord.uid;
        //usersRef.child(id).set(userDatabase (req, res))
        res.status(200).json({
            "return": "Atualizar usuário com sucesso"
        })
    })
    .catch(função(erro) {
            res.status(500).json({
                "return": error
            })
        });
```

Mas não consigo atualizar o usuário. Firebase envia-me a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
"Código": "auth / internal-error",
"Mensagem": "Ocorreu um erro interno."
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O teu código tem um erro de sintaxe. O ultimo `);` devia ser `});`

Comment: Obrigado. Postei errado aqui. Mas o problema persiste.